# A simple rhyming 'What am I?'

Tags: word, rhyme

> If particularly blunt or sharp I can hurt,
>
> I'm everywhere from pay checks to your shirt,
>
> I've more variations than there are objects on Earth,
>
> I can be measured and used and a mark of your worth,
>
> I can destroy and I can heal,
>
> Can be broken or conceal,

**What am I?**

Comment: Rot13(V pbafvqre vg gb or fbzr xvaq bs zngrevny yvxr cncre be pbggba be zrgny be jbbq)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a:

> word

If particularly blunt or sharp I can hurt:

> Not sure if this is literal but some words can hurt

I'm everywhere from pay checks to your shirt:

> Paychecks and shirts have words on them

I've more variations than there are objects on Earth:

> There are loads of words

I can be measured and used and a mark of your worth:

> Titles applied to people, either good, (eg, champion), or bad, (eg, despot). Thanks @Walkerbo

I can destroy and I can heal:

> Words can hurt someone or heal them

Can be broken or conceal:

> Your word can be broken or a secret kept. Thanks @Walkerbo

Comment: this answer was before one by @Walkerbo

Comment: @aaaaaa yes, i answered it around 30 minutes earlier

Comment: 16 minutes to be exact. Roll mouse over "answered 7 hours ago" above your name

Answer (score 4):

What am I?

> You are Words.

If particularly blunt or sharp I can hurt:

> Sharp tongues can bash and cut.

I'm everywhere from pay checks to your shirt:

> Words are used in all facets of our life, on cash, checks  and clothing.

I've more variations than there are objects on Earth:

> There are an estimated 225,000 in just the English language.

I can be measured and used and a mark of your worth:

> Titles applied to people, either good, (eg, champion), or bad, (eg, despot).

Can be broken or conceal:

> Your word can be broken or a secret kept.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Paper

If particularly blunt or sharp I can hurt,

> You can cut your finger on the edge of a paper sheet

I'm everywhere from pay checks to your shirt,

> Pay checks are on paper. Dunno about the shirt

I've more variations than there are objects on Earth,

> Can't really tell

I can be measured and used and a mark of your worth,

> Paper formats like A4 or US letter. Can be written upon

I can destroy and I can heal,

> Don't know

Can be broken or conceal

> You can tear paper apart and wrap it around stuff

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> Money

If particularly blunt or sharp I can hurt,

> Gold, which has been used as the currency of choice throughout history, could also be the material of choice for weapons such as swords, battle axes, and hammers.

I'm everywhere from pay checks to your shirt,

> The price is on our paychecks and our shirts' tags.

I've more variations than there are objects on Earth,

> There are infinite variations of numbers to represent currency.

I can be measured and used and a mark of your worth,

> It can certainly be measured and the number could tell how wealthy a person is.

I can destroy and I can heal,

> Money allows us to do so many things, either destructive or helpful.

Can be broken or conceal,

> To save your money, you may split or hide your cash somewhere.